# Permission denial while writing a file

Tags: android, kotlin, uri, file-writing

I'm writing a basic editor to user change content of the file. First i get the lines of file and store it in list like this :

```
rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { fileUri ->
                        if (fileUri != null) {
                            Consts.file = fileUri
 }
}
val context = LocalContext.current
val inputStream: InputStream? = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(Consts.file!!)
var lineList = mutableListOf<String>()
inputStream?.bufferedReader()?.forEachLine { lineList.add(it) }
```

and show the lines of it inside a lazy column and change it :

```
LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(8.dp)){
            itemsIndexed(items = lineList){index,item ->
                var textValue by remember { mutableStateOf(item) }
                Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically){
                    Text(style = TextStyle(textDirection = TextDirection.Rtl),text = "${index + 1}")
                    Box(modifier = Modifier
                        .width(1.dp)
                        .height(14.dp)
                        .background(Color.Black))
                    BasicTextField(modifier = Modifier
                        .width(IntrinsicSize.Min)
                        .padding(4.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth(),value = textValue, onValueChange = {
                        textValue = it
                        lineList = lineList.toMutableList().apply {
                            set(index, it)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
```

and after user changed the lines, i want to save the changed content line by line and :

```
                             
try{
            val outputStream = context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(Consts.file!!)
            outputStream.use {stream->
                val writer = OutputStreamWriter(stream)
                lineList.forEach{line ->
                    writer.write(line)
                }
                writer.flush()
                Log.e("Tag","file saved successfully")
            }
        }catch (e:Exception){
            Log.e("Tag","error while saving file !  ",e)
        }
```

and added these lines in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<!--this is for androids above 10-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>
    <!--this is for androids below 10-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I'll get this error :

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing >com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri >content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document%3A1000000045 from pid=5704, >uid=10191 requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()

as error said i added the MANAGE_DOCUMENTS permission in android manifest file and added grantUriPermission like this before writing to the file:

```
context.grantUriPermission("com.sina.writeeditor" , Consts.file!! , Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
```

but got same error again.

Comment: "as error said i added the MANAGE_DOCUMENTS permission in android manifest file" -- you cannot hold that permission. "and added grantUriPermission like this" -- you cannot grant yourself permission to documents owned by others. "I'll get this error" -- where did you get that `Uri` from?

Comment: @CommonsWare i edited the post i got it from a "rememberLauncherForActivityResult", and for "MANAGE_DOCUMENTS' what should permission i should use ? im trying write a file editor and MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is not providing all files access in android 10+ .

Comment: `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is not providing all files access in android 10+` That is for Android 11+ devices. Not for Q/10; And if implemented correct it gives all files access. But... it has nothing to do with that GetContent().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file uri obtained with GetContent() is not writable.

Hence that SecurityException.

You dont need any permission in manifest using GetContent().

And no permission in manifest will give you write access.

Comment: So how should i get file if it is not possible from get content ?

Comment: Do you really want to overwrite an existing file? Why? Why not create a new one?

Comment: i want to save a file that edited from the user, so you tell me i should make a new file with new edited content and save it in exact path as original file to do this, right ?

Comment: `i want to save a file that edited from the user, ` Dont understand. First you did not tell how that file was created or how the user edited it. Second: if you want to edit the file then you first have to read it contents. I dont see you doing that. You should better tell what happenend before and what should happen now.

Comment: i edited the post, sorry for misdirection.

Comment: Ok. I see. Try with ACTION_GET_DOCUMENT/OpenDocument() instead.

Comment: i used OpenDocument() and now it's working well, please edit your answer if you want.